# Reason why site_url would work in template, but not current_url?

Tags: templates, global-variables

I have the following code using the {site_url} variable, like so:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="inline" data-width="300" data-href="{site_url}">
```

However, when I changed the variable to {current_url}, it doesn't work.

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="inline" data-width="300" data-href="{current_url}">
```

Any idea why one standard global variable would work and not the other?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of EE are you using? I think current_url is a fairly new global variable. I think it was introduced in 2.5.5

Comment: Turns out we're using 2.5.2. Should have caught that when reading the documentation. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{current_url}` was only included in EE 2.5.4 so if it's older than this then that will be why it doesn't work. An alternative approach would be to either use {site_url} followed by segment variables (not too clean) or use [one](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/currentlee) [of the](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/current) [many](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/url-helper) plugins which address this shortfall prior to 2.5.4.

Personally I quite like [URL Helper](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/url-helper) as it has many useful utilities wrapped up into one handy package. It fills a lot of small holes in EE's URL handling.

Comment: Thanks Ian. We're using 2.5.2 which explains the problem. I'll use segments for now until they upgrade.